# Boolean functions and characters

Tags: functions, graph-theory, voting-theory

[image]

I'm trying to solve this, but I have no idea how to start! I'm not even sure what the question is really asking. Can anybody rephrase this and perhaps give me pointers/solutions for one of the parts?

Answer (score 1):

"Character" most likely refers to a "characteristic function", i.e. a function $\chi_S$ designed with a specific set $S$ in mind, such that $\chi_S(x)=1$ if $x\in S$ and $\chi_S(x)=0$ if not. So, for $XOR(x_1,x_2)$, the set of tuples $x$ on which $XOR(x)=1$ is $\{(0,1), (1,0)\}$. Then let that set be $S$.

Can you take it from here?

Edit: I realized that the argument $x$ could be a vector of more than 2 entries, so in general the set $S$ for the XOR function should consist of all vectors such that either $(x_1,x_2)=(1,0)$ or $(x_1,x_2)=(0,1)$, and the other entries are arbitrary.

Comment: Great! I think so. Just to check my understanding, for (a), would it simply be $S = \{ 0 ,1 \}$?

Comment: Hmm…perhaps not so. The argument $x$ is a vector of $n$ 0-1 entries (so $x=(x_1,x_2,\ldots,x_n)$). The dictator function in (a) outputs the value of the first coordinate $x_1$, and equals 1 if and only if $x_1=1$. So the vectors $x$ for which $Dict^1_n(x)=1$ consists of…what vectors? (here is a new chance for you to check your understanding) It is that set which we should take to be $S$.

Comment: the set of vectors with $x_1=1$?

Comment: Exactly :) So that is the set $S$ we need. Proceed similarly for the rest now.

Comment: Is $\chi_S(x)$ simply 1 for $x \in S$ and 0 otherwise in every case? This seems almost too simple

Comment: Yeah, that is exactly what a characteristic function is. Unless the problem text means something else, it is really that simple of a task.